# problem while importing list of lists into a text file

Tags: python

I have list of lists like this:

small example:

```
[['chr1', '+', '14409', '1440910', 'DDX11L1\n', 'DDX11L1\n_part0'], ['chr1', '+', '14409', '1440910', 'DDX11L1\n', 'DDX11L1\n_part1']]
```

I want to import it into a tab separated text file. but the problem is `\n` in `5th` and `6th` elements. in fact \n in those columns is not required. here is the code I used:

```
with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerows(listoflists)
```

but the file looks like this:

```
chr1,+,14409,1440910,"DDX11L1
","DDX11L1
_part0"
chr1,+,14409,1440910,"DDX11L1
","DDX11L1
_part1"
```

I want every list in one line. do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: wouldn't it make sense to remove all the \n characters from your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have already identified your problem, now you just needed to search around to find your answer

```
for i in listoflists:
    print([s.replace('\n', '') for s in i])
```

then continue with your printing code

```
with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerows(listoflists)
```

output:

```
chr1,+,14409,1440910,"DDX11L1","DDX11L1_part0"
chr1,+,14409,1440910,"DDX11L1","DDX11L1_part1"
```